# how to change font size in kibana dashboard version 6.6.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm currently working with Kibana version 6.6.0 and creating a dashboard with a visualization (like datatable, Region Map, Gauge, etc.). How can I change the font size of text in a datatable that is being displayed in Kibana dashboard?

[I have given the link of image. The image is taken from Kibana [Flights] Global Flight Dashboard]. This is the datatable. How can I reduce the font-size of text in that datatable?

[image: asdf]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the data table visualisation does not have any out-of-the-box feature to change its font-size. I also reviewed Kibana's product backlog at [this link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues). I am afraid, I could not find any request on this. I would recommend you to [open a feature request](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/new) if you want to see it in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available as per this [link](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2207). Please do give a plus 1 here so that it is considered for future releases.